# google tensorflow api fails with detecting libraries

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I am building a model simillar to the `google` `tensorflow` `API` one. I just want to start training the model so I pumped in this line of code.

```
    python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco.config
```

I am following the `sentdex` tutorial for training a custom object detector. When I execute this line, I get the following error.

```
    File "train.py", line 49, in <module>
 from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1- py3.6.egg\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
 from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
    File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 27, in <module>
 from object_detection.protos import input_reader_pb2
     ImportError: cannot import name 'input_reader_pb2'
```

`Sentdex` got a similar error and after he ran this code

```
    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/slim
```

everything was fine. When I try to run it, I get the following error

```
'export' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

I changed the `export` to `set` and it compiles the code but it still gives me an error.I tried adding everything i have for Python to my PATH and it still gives me the same error. The problem isn't in the PATH and i can't find a solution anywhere else so can please someone give me a hand.